# How to use global CSS variables with Svelte

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit, css-variables

As you can see on the image below, my css variables is defined but doesn't shown up on the screen. On my react app it was worked but now it seems it cannot read my css variables. I have defined a lot of 5-colored themes and I want to switch between them. Easiest way that I know is using css variables...
[image: screenshot]

I tried;

- importing global.css file in app.html via  in ,
- importing global.css file in +layout.svelte
- using :global()
- and defining them in +layout.svelte file with  tag
  as a result nothing is changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your colors are enclosed in quotes, that's just invalid CSS syntax.
(Did you copy that from same CSS-in-JS definition?)